# Good idea to warn students they were suspected of cheating?

Tags: mathematics, cheating

I am a math professor. Several of our midterm questions were posted to Chegg. We found some students who clearly used them and gave them zeroes for the exam. We also had two students where I kept going back and forth. Most of their work was fine but, in each case, there was one answer which was surprisingly close to Chegg but not so close that I thought it couldn't be a coincidence. I kept sitting on the edge and finally decided to let it go.

I've been thinking, after all grades are in, of writing these students and saying "If you were cheating, you came very close to getting caught. You should be scared about how close you came and make sure you don't do this again; you clearly know enough to pass without it. If you weren't, than I am very sorry to have suspected you." Good idea or terrible idea?

Comment: It seems redundant in any case. If you gave several students a zero for the same reason you are considering to tell others they might have gotten one, what does it add? A general reference to using online sources leading to failing the exam should suffice.

Comment: @gnometorule Please use the answer box to answer questions.

Comment: As long as the students know that you know, they should get the message.

Comment: To me (non US) it sounds very strange that you can deduct points at all for correct answers, just because they were memorized from published solutions online? (They were not using a mobile phone during the exam to copy anything, right?) My feeling is that it is up to the examiner to give suitable questions, and if their questions are identical to ones that have already benn circulated then it is not the student's fault? Or do I misunderstand the question entirely?

Comment: Echoing @Jakob's remark/query: would/does the "cheating" consist of memorizing information that was on the internet prior to the exam, or is it somehow getting access to that info _during_ the exam?

Comment: @Jakob: In this forum, there is a question about whether it is cheating to drink coffee during an exam (and many answers taking this question seriously). While the clear answer is of course no, I find it (from my culture perspective) very worrisome in what exam culture someone must grow up to ask such a question (or treat and answer it seriously). I guess there are many "extreme" exam cultures we are not used to..

Comment: @Jakob I wouldn't jump to that conclusion given that the sensible interpretation is that the questions were posted and answered during the exam. Which means that copying the solution is clear cheating. No memorizing involved...

Comment: @Jakob: In the U.S. most of us are currently in a distance-learning environment, and there's no way to prevent students from using desktop, laptop, phone, anything from accessing online answers during a test. E.g., This semester I had a totally unique question, never before posted anywhere, in a discrete math test that was posted to Chegg (incl. my hint for formatting a table in our LMS), received an answer with terms and techniques never covered in class or book, and copy-pasted verbatim to 5 student submissions, all within the 90 minute span of the test.

Comment: Related: This question on SE Math Educators about how to give online tests in the current environment, with several experiences around cheating by Chegg during the tests: https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/18477/what-are-the-best-practices-for-giving-online-tests

Comment: Was this a test done at home or online? Or were they accessing the internet from class?

Comment: As an aside, since this has not been mentioned elsewhere; if you have designed the kind of test that can easily be cheated on via a simple visit to Chegg, then you should use that as feedback that you need to improve your exam. Know that in the presence of perverse incentives (e.g. easy to cheat exam, others will do it, 1st class student will have their grade dropped due to grade normalisation if they don't also cheat, etc) cheating behaviour may not even register as morally wrong e.g. (look up literature on moral disengagement and cheating). So to some extent you are co-responsible for this.

Comment: In one course the professor had to give a final term paper instead of an exam, he said something along the lines that if all the papers come back the same, he's going to assume it's a statistical anomaly. Not so that we have a pass for cheating, but that we feel encouraged to work together if we get stuck. If the answers are close, but not enough, give them the benefit of the doubt.

Comment: The fact that you want to put an apology in your message to them (not to mention being "very" sorry) should already be a signal to yourself that it's probably not a good idea to send such a message in the first place.

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou I don't think your assessment is justified. What we're discussing is the following cheating mode: the exam starts, the student posts an exam question online during the exam, someone else (unrelated to the course) answers the exact question and posts their answer online (for a small payment), the original student copies that answer. We are not talking about questions whose answers can simply be found online independent of the exam. Such type of questions would indeed be a bad choice for open book exams (which practically all exams are right now).

Comment: @user2705196 possibly, but to the extent it may even be partly true then it's worth considering. It's not a statement intended to justify cheating by the students. I only play "devil's advocate" here because I think this particular point can be relevant, but often completely disregarded when considering "what action to take".

Comment: Notifying the students of your suspicion is a bad idea for the reasons already mentioned in the top answer by Buffy. It also reduces your chances of catching the students; instead of no longer cheating (if they were cheating), they may simply try to cover it up better next time.

Comment: Be sure to read and understand your school's academic honesty policy.  I would not be allowed to issue penalty for dishonesty without using official mechanisms to do so.

Comment: What kind of questions were these?  There's only so many correct ways to solve any given mathematical problem, so it's quite likely that some people in a large enough class would stumble upon ones that closely match each other.  If it's a word description of something, that's more suspect.  But if it's just working out equations, cheating is a little harder to detect...

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou posting on Chegg is equivalent to showing a knowledgeable person your exam and asking them for the answer.

Comment: If you want to be sneaky, put a nonsensical question on the test, then put a "solution" to it on Chegg.

Answer (score 117):

No, you should not single them out. If you have *evidence* of cheating, then charge it. If you have *suspicions* then you should swallow and ignore them so as not to prejudice the students in the future.

If you want to announce to the entire class that there were a few other cases that were *suspect*, not naming names and not singling out any individual, that would be fine and the message would be delivered.

Some people would take such a singling out very badly. Psychologically. Especially if they didn't cheat.

Comment: What do you mean with "not to prejudice the students in the future"?

Comment: @FedericoPoloni if a professor told me that I was suspected of cheating, and I did not, I would be incredibly outraged and pissed. I know for a fact I would be distracted in the course, and constantly worried whatever I did next would be under a microscope (which would be true if I was suspected, but I would be unaware of it). And it would be impossible to look at that professor with hope for any sort of academic relationship. Perhaps in years worth of time, but certainly not in a college span. Others may be more forgiving, but sometimes your reputation is all you have and that stain is deep.

Comment: Strongly seconding @J.Hirsch's comment... Things/suspicions that are voiced cannot be unsaid.

Comment: And math, being what it is, is hard to say whether the **correct** answer is due to cheating. However, if they got an answer wrong the same way, then that is more likely (still not proof, but extremely suspicious).

Comment: It should also be emphasized that many undergraduate students are under a lot of pressure, especially in their first year, as many of them are experiencing independent life for the first time. Many of them have literally never struggled in school before and have no idea what "studying" is or why you would want to do it. The *last* thing they need is a thinly-veiled "I think you cheated but I can't prove it" email from the professor (assuming innocence, of course). Obviously, those same students will also have no answer if you demand to see their studying process.

Comment: I think announcement to the whole class is also profitable towards the people who might have actually cheated without even being suspected. If I was to cheat, and to learn people have been caught cheating, and that others have been suspected and I'm none of them, I probably would feel even more confident. While knowing I might be among the ones being suspected, I might be hesitating next time...

Comment: I can think of one exception to this: the case where it superficially appears that a student has plagiarized a published source, but on closer inspection, it turns out s/he has given proper attribution in some subtle way.  I think it's fair play to warn that student "I suggest you make your citations more obvious in future, in case you find yourself falsely suspected of plagiarism."

Comment: @DanielHatton, yes, I agree. But that is really just a proper lesson on good academic practice. But that is also a lesson for the entire class, I think.

Comment: I can say I was falsely accused of cheating because I and another student made the same wrong guess about something that hadn't been taught yet (basically, the difference between a harmonic and an overtone), and I still hold a grudge against that TA 25 years later.

Comment: I was accused of cheating in high school when I hadn't. I didn't like it, still remember it. But, I also realized that he _thought_ I was cheating. He was just wrong, that's all. He was one of the best teachers I've ever had, and I still have tremendous respect for him 40 years later. Nevertheless, I like this answer for the middle paragraph.

Answer (score 23):

If you suspect cheating, one option is to ask the students directly to explain how they got answers that were so similar to the online source.  In my experience, this often results in an immediate confession on the part of the students.  If they come up with a story that's hard to believe, but you don't have enough evidence to get through the disciplinary process, then you can drop the matter.

Comment: I completely agree with both Buffy's answer and this answer.  Don't accuse students without strong evidence, but depending on how much you care and how sketchy their exam looks, you can require some students to chat with you to "discuss concerns about their exams" before you assign them a final grade.  If your university has something like an Academic Integrity Office, you might chat with them first about what to do.

Comment: Brian, my experience this semester has been the opposite. The email conversation usually goes like this: student asks why they got a zero. I say because they copied the answer to q2 from an online source. They reply that no, that they studied very hard and that all their work is theirs. I send them a screenshot of the online answer they copied. They reply that they were "self-studying", and that it was "the only time", that their life is hard, and that they are  in a small village in country X. I send them a screenshot of another answer and report them to the Dean.

Comment: I've also had students who deny cheating despite evidence showing verbatim copying of large chunks of text.  Since the copied text itself is sufficient evidence of plagiarism, I just send the charges on to the dean.

Comment: @MartinArgerami I think student reactions over email and in person/Zoom can be quite different.  If you schedule a conversation with them and ask them to explain how they got their solution and why they wrote such-and-such, some people who copied will confess readily, though it's true that others deny deny deny.

Comment: @Kimball: makes sense. Though in person I've also heard the most outrageous excuses.

Comment: It feels a bit weird to punish only those students honest/stupid enough to admit, as this answer suggests.

Answer (score 2):

If you ask Chegg, they would supply student data they hold. This includes not only those who asked the questions but also those who viewed the answers. If you have the right clauses in the honor code preventing students from seeking unauthorized help, then you can take students to the disciplinary tribunal with the evidence you obtained from Chegg.

Answer (score -7):

Let's say I'm the student suspected of cheating and look at this from my perspective:

**Case 1**: I cheated, and receive this email warning me I came close to being caught. This should be a good result. It would act as deterrence - after all, next time I might not be so lucky. Only thing to pay attention to here is to not reveal the evidence against me, since otherwise I might be tempted to cheat again except this time also to cover any tracks.

**Case 2**: I didn't cheat. In this case the warning is irrelevant to me. Like, the conditional is false, so whatever follows it is irrelevant. After all, the statement "if you cheated then pigs fly" is true! The allegation would only become a nuisance if I had to invest time and effort to fend it off (which I presumably don't in this case), or if it became public (which it doesn't have to, if you send private email).

If you are very worried about case 2 (which is reasonable), you could try looking around to see the effect of false allegations in online forums such as StackExchange. We do for example have [rules against multiple accounts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57682/how-should-sockpuppets-be-handled-on-stack-exchange). One can never actually be sure that two accounts are actually the same person, which will invariably lead to false accusations and possibly investigations. I don't actually have the statistics on how people react, but perhaps a mod will be able to say. My experience elsewhere is that people get annoyed if they have to mount a defense, but if it's just being told they've been suspected, they might even react with laughter.

**Edit**: Based on the comments, different people come to different conclusions on this because they interpret things differently. I for example would consider the proposed email closer to being exonerated than being accused, but many others don't. Clearly the dividing line between the two very different reactions is extremely fine. If you do send the letter, you will have to word it very carefully. At that point, it might be better to just sidestep the potential quagmire entirely and not bother.

Comment: "@anonymous, I suspect you are actually Buffy who's posted this question to upvote your own answer so you can get more rep on your main account. If you are actually Buffy, you've come very close to being caught. If you are not actually Buffy, I am very sorry to have suspected you." I actually feel pretty ridiculous typing that out, and I very much think that you are more likely to laugh than to feel outraged. If you do feel outraged, then perhaps it's a reason not to send the warning.

Comment: I disagree with case 2. You seem to assume that students think like machines. In reality, I'd assume that most students would intrepret a sentence starting with "If you did cheat" as "I suspect you of cheating" (if the sentence was not given in a complete abstract way or is complete nonsense like your comment). Are you familiar with Schulz von Thun's communication theory?

Comment: If I was wrongly accused in cheating I would probably put a formal complaint again the professor. I would most certainly not "see the warning as irrelevant".

Comment: @Allure That's not a good analogy because you don't hold any authority over Buffy, and the accusation is pretty silly. Imagine instead that a police man came at your door and told you that have been investigated for some crime at a place that you frequently visit (i.e., you could plausibly be suspected of this crime), but they didn't gather *quite* enough evidence to charge you. You certainly wouldn't just shrug this off.

Comment: @Inkblot To be fair, if the professor acted in good faith and followed regulations, this complaint would go nowhere.

Comment: @Inkblot this is not an accusation. An accusation would force you to mount a defense. What the OP is suggesting is a warning that you were suspected, which is a lot less severe.

Comment: @xLeitix I can't say for certain since it's not happened to me, but I suspect I would indeed shrug it off. Why wouldn't I? I haven't even been accused of wrongdoing. Here's another comparison: suppose MH380 were found today and all the passengers are still alive. I'm one of the passengers. Would I be offended that I was investigated as a possible terrorist? I honestly have a hard time seeing it. In fact, I'd probably be more troubled if the authorities didn't investigate me.

Comment: @user111388 it is possible I assume students think like machines and they don't. I can't prove it. All I can say is that I have seen sockpuppet investigations and people's reaction to being discovered that they were investigated. It is usually not outrage. I don't know how much of it is due to online disinhibition, however; getting suspected in real life is presumably more troubling.

Comment: Wasn't there an American guy who said about Guantanamo "It's better to torture an innocent person than to let a terrorist go"? I'd be much scared about being suspected a terrorist. It's similar with a prof: of course, a prof doesn't torture students - yet every examination has some sort of biases. I'd also wouldn't like to hear that a prof is biased against me because he suspects I cheated/didn't like my outfit/gender/whatever.

Comment: @user111388 It's not like the OP can forget they suspected the student. If this suspicion will eventually lead to the OP being biased against the student, would the student prefer not to know what the OP is suggesting they reveal? That sounds suspiciously like "ignorance is bliss".

Comment: This answer greatly, greatly underestimates the devastating effects a wrong accusation of cheating can have on a student.

Comment: @Stef except, to emphasize again, what the OP is proposing is *not* an accusation.

Comment: I considered adding "just because you say in a comment that it is not an accusation, doesn't make it any less of an accusation" in my last comment. Apparently I should have. You are obviously very detached emotionally from this and believe that it's not a big deal. But it is. For the students it is. A false accusation like that, no matter how you call it, can have devastating effects on the student and might very well cause a lot of otherwise hard-working students to completely stop working for your class, and lose faith in university in general.

Comment: @Stef Except, again, it is *not* an accusation (and equally, just because you say it is an accusation doesn't make it an accusation). It becomes an accusation if the OP actually tells the student to present their defense. Compare: a SE mod could investigate right now if you are actually Buffy's alt account, and if they don't tell you, you would never know you've been investigated. Are you saying you don't want to know you've been investigated? Again, that sounds very much like "ignorance is bliss".

Comment: @Allure Clearly you have never been wrongly accused of cheating. It doesn't matter that the accusation is not official, nor does it matter that the teacher adds "if you did not cheat, I am very sorry that I suspected you". Once the words are said, the damage is done.

Comment: No, I have no account other than Buffy (and never have had). You are _really_ mistaken, and insulting. I don't need to game the system here. I just answer a lot of questions.

Comment: Both of your "cases" are flawed. In the first case, not revealing your "evidence" is improper. In the second, it is anything but irrelevant to a person to be unjustly accused and have a cloud remaining over them in the future. I won't downvote because you don't recommend improper actions here, but you should rethink your assumptions.

Comment: Ah, maybe your accusation in the comment was just a joke. You "suspect" me of cheating, but have no evidence. If I'm a student in this situation, my opinion of you just went down a few notches.

Comment: @xLeitix: As other remarked, being falsely accused in cheating *is a big deal*. And if I had received an email "I think you were cheating, but if you weren't then no biggie", I'd have taken it as an accusation of cheating. I don't expect a complaint over this to get anywhere, I expect it to be put on record, and I expect it to cause a minor headache to the department chair and the professor, who should at the very least be more selective of their claims in the future.

Comment: @Inkblot the proposed email doesn't say "I think you were cheating". In fact, it pretty clearly says "I think you weren't cheating", since if the OP thought it was cheating, they would've pressed a real accusation.

Comment: @Buffy I certainly don't think you were gaming the system. It was just a conveniently available, almost certainly false example to illustrate what it'd feel like for the OP. I'm sorry to have used you as an example though, it was in retrospect pretty bad. I can't edit the comment anymore though. Any suggestions? I could delete it.

Comment: I am actually curious now how the reaction would be if the letter is of the form "you were suspected of cheating, but the case was dropped due to lack of evidence. If you were cheating, you came very close to getting caught ...". I am also curious if that reaction would change if it were a TA sending it instead, worded as "the professor suspected you of cheating, but there wasn't enough evidence. Just FYI, and if you were cheating, you came very close to getting caught ...".

Comment: Actually, I think it would be a mistake to delete the comment. It serves as a warning all its own. Your comment, my reaction.

Comment: @Buffy even then I don't consider the comment & your reaction as a warning for what might happen if the OP goes ahead though - the comment was directed at anonymous and there is no third person in the OP's scenario. It was a bad comment in the way that it's usually not a good idea to make a joke at someone else's expense (again, apologies for doing that).

Comment: The suggested email is NOT saying "I think you weren't cheating." It's saying "I think you were cheating, but I don't have quite enough evidence to prove it." That's entirely different from "we investigated you and cleared you of any wrong doing." There's no way that can do any good if the students weren't actually cheating, since it's not like they can make their work less suspicious.

Comment: Case 1 might not be deterrence at all. I can imagine it gives the student this feeling: "Aha, so that kind of cheating is enough to raise suspicion, but not enough to charge accusation. Next time I cheat, I'll be doing it better." Without any deterrence/scare

Answer (score -8):

Actually, I wonder why this is a problem at all.
Especially math is about understanding and solving a problem. And not about how well you can find external information.

If exam questions are testing understanding and solving, it won't help your students when they are looking up the answers somewhere else. Therefore it doesn't matter if they look up answers. So I think you are fixing the wrong thing here.

Edit:
For me it was not clear the questions were posted during the exam. That makes a bit of a difference. When remembering my math exams: besides the answer I had to give an explanation why the answer was correct. Without explanation you got only a fraction of the points. Depending on the teacher, even with a correct answer.
When cheating was suspected you had to clarify your explanation. Which you are not able to if you cheated.

Comment: I don't follow the logic here. If a question (which is testing understanding and solving) has been posted in advance online and you memorise and then transcribe the answer in the exam, in what way does it "not help the students"? It helps them to pass the exam without the need to demonstrate any understanding or solving.

Comment: This question is not about memorizing answers. The exam in question had been posted and solved online *during* the exam to be shared with the students taking the exam! This is the type of cheating we're talking about.